# What's an "injective" function $f(i, j)$ such that $i \lt j, k \lt l \implies f(i,k) \lt f(j,l)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

For example $f(i,j) = i^2 + j^2$ won't work because there are numbers that can be written as the sum of squares in two ways.  It only has to work on the natural numbers.  It only has to be injective across differing pair sets $\{i,j\} \neq \{k,l\}$ and it should be commutative: $f(i,j) = f(j,i)$.

Comment: Does $\exp$ work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $, I think $f(i,j)=2^i 3^j$ will work.

Comment: This is not "commutative," $f(i,j)\neq f(j,i)$ unless $i=j$.

Comment: This is a good idea though.  I will select this as an answer since I found problems with my motivation part.  The non-commutativity isn't as bad.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0$ (if not, just shift everything by $1$):

Let
$$ f(i,j) = \left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{i(i+1)}{2} + j &\text{ if }i\le j \\ f(j,i) &\text{ if } i> j\end{matrix}\right. $$
The idea is to let $f(0,0) = 0$, $f(1,0) = 1$, $f(1,1) = 2$, $f(2,0) = 3$, $f(2,1) = 4$, $f(2,2) = 5$, $f(3,0)=6$, and so on.